# C# HttpClient Post returns no content but Postman does

Tags: c#, xml, api, post, xml-serialization

I'm trying to get some Data from a WebAPI via the POST method. The API is a public transport data API and sends/ receives XML serialized data. When I call the API from Postman I get the data, when I try to do the same from C# although I receive a Message with the status code 200 the `ContentLength` is `-1` and I can't read any data from it.

My C# API Call and stream generation:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
serializer.Serialize(stream, toSend);

HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

HttpResponseMessage response = await 
    client.PostAsync("https://api.opentransportdata.swiss/trias",
            new StringContent(new StreamReader(stream, 
                Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"));
```

Where my `stream` is a `MemoryStream` that contains my XML Serialized data.
The Response Message is `200` (OK) but the content is empty, when I do the same with Postman it works.
Here's the serialized XML Data I'm sending that I read from the Stream the same way I'm reading it to send it to the API

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Trias xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.vdv.de/trias">
  <ServiceRequest>
    <siri_x003A_RequestTimestamp>2018-10-09T10:31:56.2886025+02:00</siri_x003A_RequestTimestamp>
    <siri_x003A_RequestorRef>SEUS</siri_x003A_RequestorRef>
    <RequestPayload>
      <TripRequest>
        <Origin>
          <LocationRef>
            <StopPointRef>8500320</StopPointRef>
          </LocationRef>
        </Origin>
        <Destination>
          <LocationRef>
            <StopPointRef>8500322</StopPointRef>
          </LocationRef>
        </Destination>
      </TripRequest>
      <Params>
        <NumberOfResults>0</NumberOfResults>
        <IncludeTrackSections>false</IncludeTrackSections>
        <IncludeLegProjection>false</IncludeLegProjection>
        <IncludeIntermediateStops>false</IncludeIntermediateStops>
      </Params>
    </RequestPayload>
  </ServiceRequest>
</Trias>
```

And here's the expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Trias xmlns="http://www.vdv.de/trias" version="1.1">
    <ServiceDelivery>
        <ResponseTimestamp xmlns="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri">2018-10-09T08:33:26Z</ResponseTimestamp>
        <ProducerRef xmlns="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri">EFAController10.2.9.62-WIN-G0NJHFUK71P</ProducerRef>
        <Status xmlns="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri">true</Status>
        <MoreData>false</MoreData>
        <Language>de</Language>
        <DeliveryPayload>
            <TripResponse>
                <TripResult>
                    <ResultId>ID-A24DE912-0263-4067-AD73-591DF01F4B05</ResultId>
                    <Trip>
                        <TripId>ID-E442EC5E-1B70-4E9D-836F-47585406D2F7</TripId>
                        <Duration>PT7M</Duration>
                        <StartTime>2018-10-09T08:19:00Z</StartTime>
                        <EndTime>2018-10-09T08:26:00Z</EndTime>
                        <Interchanges>0</Interchanges>
                        <TripLeg>
                            <LegId>1</LegId>
                            <TimedLeg>
                                <LegBoard>
                                    <StopPointRef>8500320</StopPointRef>
                                    <StopPointName>
                                        <Text>Stein-Säckingen</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </StopPointName>
                                    <PlannedBay>
                                        <Text>2</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </PlannedBay>
                                    <ServiceDeparture>
                                        <TimetabledTime>2018-10-09T08:19:00Z</TimetabledTime>
                                    </ServiceDeparture>
                                    <StopSeqNumber>1</StopSeqNumber>
                                </LegBoard>
                                <LegAlight>
                                    <StopPointRef>8500322</StopPointRef>
                                    <StopPointName>
                                        <Text>Laufenburg</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </StopPointName>
                                    <PlannedBay>
                                        <Text>1</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </PlannedBay>
                                    <ServiceArrival>
                                        <TimetabledTime>2018-10-09T08:26:00Z</TimetabledTime>
                                    </ServiceArrival>
                                    <StopSeqNumber>2</StopSeqNumber>
                                </LegAlight>
                                <Service>
                                    <OperatingDayRef>2018-10-09</OperatingDayRef>
                                    <JourneyRef>odp:04001::H:j18:17235:17235</JourneyRef>
                                    <LineRef>odp:04001::H</LineRef>
                                    <DirectionRef>outward</DirectionRef>
                                    <Mode>
                                        <PtMode>rail</PtMode>
                                        <RailSubmode>suburbanRailway</RailSubmode>
                                        <Name>
                                            <Text>S-Bahn</Text>
                                            <Language>de</Language>
                                        </Name>
                                    </Mode>
                                    <PublishedLineName>
                                        <Text>1</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </PublishedLineName>
                                    <OperatorRef>odp:11</OperatorRef>
                                    <OriginText>
                                        <Text></Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </OriginText>
                                    <DestinationStopPointRef>8500322</DestinationStopPointRef>
                                    <DestinationText>
                                        <Text>Laufenburg</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </DestinationText>
                                </Service>
                            </TimedLeg>
                        </TripLeg>
                    </Trip>
                </TripResult>
                <TripResult>
                    <ResultId>ID-CE13C278-DFBE-4AFF-8318-1E96EEE6FA9B</ResultId>
                    <Trip>
                        <TripId>ID-832873CC-4085-4131-9265-D5EF1F80DBF6</TripId>
                        <Duration>PT25M</Duration>
                        <StartTime>2018-10-09T08:35:00Z</StartTime>
                        <EndTime>2018-10-09T09:00:00Z</EndTime>
                        <Interchanges>0</Interchanges>
                        <TripLeg>
                            <LegId>1</LegId>
                            <InterchangeLeg>
                                <InterchangeMode>walk</InterchangeMode>
                                <LegStart>
                                    <StopPointRef>8500320</StopPointRef>
                                    <LocationName>
                                        <Text>Stein-Säckingen</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </LocationName>
                                </LegStart>
                                <LegEnd>
                                    <StopPointRef>8572748</StopPointRef>
                                    <LocationName>
                                        <Text>Stein-Säckingen, Bahnhof</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </LocationName>
                                </LegEnd>
                                <TimeWindowStart>2018-10-09T08:35:00Z</TimeWindowStart>
                                <TimeWindowEnd>2018-10-09T08:39:00Z</TimeWindowEnd>
                                <Duration>PT4M</Duration>
                            </InterchangeLeg>
                        </TripLeg>
                        <TripLeg>
                            <LegId>2</LegId>
                            <TimedLeg>
                                <LegBoard>
                                    <StopPointRef>8572748</StopPointRef>
                                    <StopPointName>
                                        <Text>Stein-Säckingen, Bahnhof</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </StopPointName>
                                    <ServiceDeparture>
                                        <TimetabledTime>2018-10-09T08:39:00Z</TimetabledTime>
                                    </ServiceDeparture>
                                    <StopSeqNumber>1</StopSeqNumber>
                                </LegBoard>
                                <LegAlight>
                                    <StopPointRef>8572403</StopPointRef>
                                    <StopPointName>
                                        <Text>Laufenburg, Bahnhof</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </StopPointName>
                                    <ServiceArrival>
                                        <TimetabledTime>2018-10-09T08:56:00Z</TimetabledTime>
                                    </ServiceArrival>
                                    <StopSeqNumber>10</StopSeqNumber>
                                </LegAlight>
                                <Service>
                                    <OperatingDayRef>2018-10-09</OperatingDayRef>
                                    <JourneyRef>odp:01143::R:j18:14332:14332</JourneyRef>
                                    <LineRef>odp:01143::R</LineRef>
                                    <DirectionRef>return</DirectionRef>
                                    <Mode>
                                        <PtMode>bus</PtMode>
                                        <BusSubmode>regionalBus</BusSubmode>
                                        <Name>
                                            <Text>Bus</Text>
                                            <Language>de</Language>
                                        </Name>
                                    </Mode>
                                    <PublishedLineName>
                                        <Text>143</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </PublishedLineName>
                                    <OperatorRef>odp:801</OperatorRef>
                                    <Attribute>
                                        <Text>
                                            <Text>Linie 143: 1555</Text>
                                            <Language>de</Language>
                                        </Text>
                                        <Code>Y3933</Code>
                                        <Mandatory>false</Mandatory>
                                    </Attribute>
                                    <OriginText>
                                        <Text></Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </OriginText>
                                    <DestinationText>
                                        <Text>Laufenburg, Bahnhof                               &#xD;</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </DestinationText>
                                </Service>
                            </TimedLeg>
                        </TripLeg>
                        <TripLeg>
                            <LegId>3</LegId>
                            <InterchangeLeg>
                                <InterchangeMode>walk</InterchangeMode>
                                <LegStart>
                                    <StopPointRef>8572403</StopPointRef>
                                    <LocationName>
                                        <Text>Laufenburg, Bahnhof</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </LocationName>
                                </LegStart>
                                <LegEnd>
                                    <StopPointRef>8500322</StopPointRef>
                                    <LocationName>
                                        <Text>Laufenburg</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </LocationName>
                                </LegEnd>
                                <TimeWindowStart>2018-10-09T08:56:00Z</TimeWindowStart>
                                <TimeWindowEnd>2018-10-09T09:00:00Z</TimeWindowEnd>
                                <Duration>PT4M</Duration>
                            </InterchangeLeg>
                        </TripLeg>
                    </Trip>
                </TripResult>
                <TripResult>
                    <ResultId>ID-7C9B4974-1D9D-4828-98BB-5A7022CD55B1</ResultId>
                    <Trip>
                        <TripId>ID-2FB9793D-93E8-495D-9802-0ECC6C4B98F3</TripId>
                        <Duration>PT6M</Duration>
                        <StartTime>2018-10-09T09:19:00Z</StartTime>
                        <EndTime>2018-10-09T09:25:00Z</EndTime>
                        <Interchanges>0</Interchanges>
                        <TripLeg>
                            <LegId>1</LegId>
                            <TimedLeg>
                                <LegBoard>
                                    <StopPointRef>8500320</StopPointRef>
                                    <StopPointName>
                                        <Text>Stein-Säckingen</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </StopPointName>
                                    <PlannedBay>
                                        <Text>2</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </PlannedBay>
                                    <ServiceDeparture>
                                        <TimetabledTime>2018-10-09T09:19:00Z</TimetabledTime>
                                        <EstimatedTime>2018-10-09T09:19:00Z</EstimatedTime>
                                    </ServiceDeparture>
                                    <StopSeqNumber>1</StopSeqNumber>
                                </LegBoard>
                                <LegAlight>
                                    <StopPointRef>8500322</StopPointRef>
                                    <StopPointName>
                                        <Text>Laufenburg</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </StopPointName>
                                    <PlannedBay>
                                        <Text>1</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </PlannedBay>
                                    <ServiceArrival>
                                        <TimetabledTime>2018-10-09T09:26:00Z</TimetabledTime>
                                        <EstimatedTime>2018-10-09T09:25:00Z</EstimatedTime>
                                    </ServiceArrival>
                                    <StopSeqNumber>2</StopSeqNumber>
                                </LegAlight>
                                <Service>
                                    <OperatingDayRef>2018-10-09</OperatingDayRef>
                                    <JourneyRef>odp:04001::H:j18:17239:17239</JourneyRef>
                                    <LineRef>odp:04001::H</LineRef>
                                    <DirectionRef>outward</DirectionRef>
                                    <Mode>
                                        <PtMode>rail</PtMode>
                                        <RailSubmode>suburbanRailway</RailSubmode>
                                        <Name>
                                            <Text>S-Bahn</Text>
                                            <Language>de</Language>
                                        </Name>
                                    </Mode>
                                    <PublishedLineName>
                                        <Text>1</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </PublishedLineName>
                                    <OperatorRef>odp:11</OperatorRef>
                                    <OriginText>
                                        <Text></Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </OriginText>
                                    <DestinationStopPointRef>8500322</DestinationStopPointRef>
                                    <DestinationText>
                                        <Text>Laufenburg</Text>
                                        <Language>de</Language>
                                    </DestinationText>
                                </Service>
                            </TimedLeg>
                        </TripLeg>
                    </Trip>
                </TripResult>
            </TripResponse>
        </DeliveryPayload>
    </ServiceDelivery>
</Trias>
```

You can try this for yourself [here](https://opentransportdata.swiss/de/cookbook/abfahrts-ankunftsanzeiger/) (just change the "Template" to "TripRequest")

Comment: could you please add your all code of API call so we have to look on how u generate that `stream`

Comment: @ershoaib updated the Code Block ;)

Comment: Best way of solving issues like this is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Then compare the Postman results with your code.  Usually the solution is to add missing header(s) into the HttpClient.  The The httpClient does not automatically add headers to request like other http method do.

Comment: @jdweng I've also tried this with the `HttpWebRequest` which automatically adds the headers needed. And I've also added the headers to the API call manually but still doesn't work. And as far as I know, Postman also doesn't add any headers. The `HttpClient` has a Authorization header and the `PostAsync` method also added the `Content-Type text/xml` header

Comment: how u call it from postman please show your postman screenshot

Comment: @ershoaib here's my screenshot from Postman: https://i.imgur.com/x4xWQp2.png

Comment: tryto add this header => `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");` above `HttpResponseMessage `

Comment: @ershoaib this just throws an error, I tried adding it another way (`client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));` But it still doesn't work

Comment: @jdweng I checked, it is adding all necessary Headers automatically

Comment: could you please add your `toSend` code. I'll try on my side

Comment: @ershoaib I have a custom Model that I'm serializing, but here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PSLDtfLy5oHkQcT2WQwzlnf_u1Vy8Gtz is the xml the serialization generates and that I'm sending to the API

Comment: ok try to set authorization token to your client like `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");` and also add this `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");` add those as it is do not try to modify it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181550/discussion-between-mindswipe-and-ershoaib).

Comment: @ershoaib I figuted it out, look at my answer. I feel very stupid

Comment: So the header was different like I said.  The encoding was wrong and had to be fixed.

Comment: @jdweng the Content Header was set wrong yes, but not the Message Header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
In the `client.PostAsync(...)` I was telling the API I am posting `Encoding.UTF8` encoded data, but my serializer was generating `ibm850` encoded Data

Comment: I figured it out already but i think it not problem so I was not telling you to encode it from utf8 to ibm850, but anyway glad to hear you have get rid from your problem :)